# How to hide some elements on the page via css

Tags: css, wordpress, portfolio

Just got this template

http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress/photo-fullscreen-responsive-wordpress-theme-flicker/

And can't locate how to change these elements via css

[image]

4 column portfolio page.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'll have greater chance to find someone to help you, if you provide a link to actual theme installation.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to accomplish. but looking from the title you need to set the elements you want to hide in your Css on Display:none

Comment: I'm referring to this page http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/flicker/portfolio-4-columns/ You can see the elements that I want to hide on the screenshot above.

Comment: @SamColins please take a tour of the help section and see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you are seeking debugging help, you must provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself

Comment: @pete Honestly I do not understand what's wrong with the question. I read those articles. Thanks

Comment: @SamColins Where's the code in the question?  You can't just link to an offsite resource - this site is intended to be a useful reference site.  If you link to an external site and then fix it, when people who may have a similar problem come to use the link, they won't see what the problem is as you have fixed it (or the link may be dead if it is in a dev environment that is removed)

Answer (score 1):

For hiding Both buttons

```
.likes_and_share { display: none; }
```

For hiding Share button

```
.page_share { display: none; }
```

For hiding Like button

```
.page_likes_add { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked fine.

Comment: No problem, please don't forget to check it as answer.

Answer (score -2):

Basically u need javascript to hide your element . You can use .hide() method which is present in jquery .

but still you want to hid an element by using css then u should go through like that

**javascript code**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) 
{
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if(e.style.display == 'block')
         e.style.display = 'none';
     else
         e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, here is the page I'm referring to http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/flicker/portfolio-4-columns/